# java.awt.color return color name not RGB value

Tags: java

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I read about 7 other questions that were similar and none of them had answers anywhere close to what I'm looking for. I also ventured past the first two pages of Google search results and still couldn't find an answer.

I don't care about all the colors in the world, I just want to use the ones that are already in the java Color class (i.e "red", "black", "green").

I'm writing a program for an intro Java class and the professor said to declare "a private Color data field named guitarColor that defines the color of the guitar. The default value should be Color.Red." His example output shows the color returning as "getColor(): Red". So I need to use the color class to get the output in this format.

When I use the java.awt.color class and input something like Color.RED, I want it to return "Red", not "java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]". How can I do this?

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Guitar g1 = new Guitar(); 

    System.out.println("getColor() result: " + g1.getColor());

    }
}


public class Guitar {    

    private Color guitarColor;

    public Guitar () {
        guitarColor = Color.RED;
    }

   public Color getColor() {
       return guitarColor;
   }


}
```

Output:

```
getColor() result: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
```

Comment: I think you need to show some code..

Comment: What I'd do: create my own enum or Map to link Strings to Colors

Comment: But having said that, there is no one-size-fits all answer. What String should be returned for `Color(130, 23, 199)`? That's why you should write your own code that links a subset of Colors to corresponding Strings. So yes, as @RobGorman suggests -- please show some code.

Comment: @RobGorman I updated with a link to the code.

Comment: Please don't link to code. Include it in your post, properly formatted.

Comment: Then try to do as suggested -- link your String with your date with either a Map or an enum. Also, please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: if you simply want RED to be "RED" then create an enum of all the colors a guitar can be and use those and not the java.awt.Color class since you aren't using the Color class for what it's used for

Comment: ok but did the professor's getColor() return a Color or did it return a String??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a function in the guitar class that deciphers what color the guitar is and returns the `String` representation of that color and not the actual `Color` object. Try this

```
public String getColorOfGuitar() {

    if(guitarColor.equals(Color.RED))
        return "RED";
    else if(guitarColor.equals(Color.BLUE))
        return "BLUE";
    else if(guitarColor.equals(Color.YELLOW))
        return "YELLOW";
    else
        return "Unknown Color";
}
```

Now when you call the method it will return a String representation of that Color

```
System.out.println("getColorOfGuitar() result: " + g1.getColorOfGuitar()); //--> getColor() result: RED
```